# The lack of foreign languages section on Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs, languages

I paid attention that on [Stack Overflow Careers](https://careers.stackoverflow.com) there is no a section describing the knowledge of the foreign languages by the person. Please, consider adding this block to the user profile. This parameter might be significant for the employer.

Comment: Couldn't an employer or candidate simply add it as one of the skills in the skill list, similar to a programming language, framework, etc?

Comment: While we're talking about the foreign languages, it's very important to specify what is the exactly level (speaking, reading, writing) of the languages has been acquired by a person. Besides, where exactly there is a block with *skills*? There are a *technologies*, *education*, *experience* sections, but not the *skills*. I would add the separate section, dedicated to the foreign languages.

Comment: I see.  Well, in the existing profiles it appears people put language expertise in their top description, and employers put language requirements in their job description.  While it might be useful for some positions, I wonder how important and common these requirements are.  If careers was expended to include a language block, would it affect over 10% of the job listings or candidate listings, or is this a relatively rare need?

Comment: Of course there is always place for workarounds, e.g, put language expertise in their top description, but IMHO, it's better to supply a solid approach to such issue, and do it in a more elegant way, like the industry leader does. BTW, this feature is especially important for the relocation offers, where the language requirement may be a part of a baseline skills.